# Яндекс пробки получить цифру

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Нужно получить балл пробок в определённом городе от Яндекс пробок.
В документации не нашёл получения отдельно бала, есть только карта с включенным уже отображением пробок.
Есть ли возможность получить его?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Яндекс.Карты API нельзя получить отдельно какой-то параметр карт с пробками, например, балл пробок, без отображения слоя пробок, а наоборот - можно (иначе нарушение правил пользования Яндекс.Картами).

Подробнее **[тут](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/51079)**.

С другой стороны был уже [**подобный топик**](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/49236).

Comment: И что будет за нарушение?

Comment: @Alex78191 я думаю, лучше спросить у них :) возможно, ограничат вам доступ к API.